# вычисляемый столбец

Tags: python, pandas

Создал новый столбец "cfo" в датафрейме на основе имеющегося "кто", теперь необходимо в новом столбце на основании результатов подставить названия например: если получили 03 то заменить на АТК, если получили 80 то заменить на АТС

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Лист Microsoft Excel.XLSX") 
x["cfo"]= x["кто"].astype(str).str[4:6]
print(x)
```

[image: ВИД ИЗ ПАЙЧАРМА]

Comment: Пример кода, результата и исходных данных должен быть в воспроизводимом виде. Иначе вопрос будет закрыт. Зачем нам ваш скриншот?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/7485582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть датафрейм, например:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cfo':[10, "AA", 4.9]})
```

```
   cfo
0   10
1   AA
2  4.9
```

то, получить новый столбец с желаемым результатом можно простым маппингом по словарю:

```
subs = {10:"ten", "AA":"3as", 4.9:"fournine"} # словарь для замены
df["кто"] = df["cfo"]
df = df.replace({"кто":subs})
```

теперь df:

```
   cfo       кто
0   10       ten
1   AA       3as
2  4.9  fournine​
```

Либо еще короче, с тем же результатом:

```
df = df.assign(кто=df["cfo"].map(subs))
```